# Converting list of strings into C style array

Tags: c++, arrays, list, winsock

I have an `std::list<std::wstring>`

```
[0] = "abc"
[1] = "wds"
[2] = "rew"
[n] = ...
```

(nevermind the index on the list it's just for the example)

Is there any simple way to convert it into a classic C byte array so that I can send it using winsocks `send()` function?

Comment: You'll need to explain what you want your byte array to look like. For example, do you mean concatenate narrow versions of those strings with some sort of separator?

Answer (score 2):

Warning: I've not compiled this. But it should give you the idea. Basically you just make your C style array and append the data from each string into it:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> cArray;

// Optional: Calculate the length of the desired byte array in advance
std::size_t actualSize = 1 + strings.size(); // stringLengths + number of strings + 1
for (std::wstring const& source : strings)
{
    actualSize += source.size();
}
cArray.reserve(actualSize);
// End optional bits

for (std::wstring const& source : strings)
{
    cArray.insert(cArray.end(), source.begin(), source.end());
    cArray.push_back(L'\0'); // null terminate
}

// double null terminate?
cArray.push_back(L'\0');

char const* cByteArray = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(cArray.data());
```

Comment: `std::vector<wchar_t>` is not a "classic C byte array" — at best, you're missing an important closing step.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, it is; it just does the allocation and deletion of it for you. If you need a pointer to the underlying buffer you can call `data()`.

Comment: @Lightness: (Also, the point is not to give the OP drop-in code; the point is to describe how one would do this.)

Comment: No, `std::vector<wchar_t>::data` is not "a classic C byte array" either. `wchar_t` are (usually) not bytes. This is not about "drop-in code"; it's about your answer explaining everything except what was actually asked for.

Comment: @Lightness: Ah, I see. I didn't see the "C style **byte** array". It does put the data into a C style array (which is what the question title asked for).

Comment: Now you've got it ;) +1